# Visual Studio Extensibility: How to control the loading order of components?

Tags: visual-studio, vsix, vs-extensibility, vsixmanifest

I have a Visual Studio extension which includes a Package and a Tagger in the same VSIX.

When the Package is loaded, it initializes a few things, including a logger.  The Tagger uses the logger.  This all works for me, but on one customer machine the Tagger is loaded before the Package, and crashes because the logger hasn't been initialized yet.

**How do I express to Visual Studio that it should always load the Package before loading the Tagger?**

The Package looks like this:

```
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.NoSolution_string)]
[ProvideAutoLoad(VSConstants.UICONTEXT.SolutionExists_string)]
public sealed class EntrianInlineWatchPackage : Package ...
```

The Tagger looks like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IViewTaggerProvider))]
[ContentType("C/C++")]
[TextViewRole(PredefinedTextViewRoles.Document)]
[TagType(typeof(ValueTag))]
public class ValueTaggerProvider : IViewTaggerProvider
{
    [Import]
    internal IClassifierAggregatorService AggregatorService;

    public ITagger<T> CreateTagger<T>(ITextView textView, ITextBuffer buffer) where T : ITag
    {
        ...
        return buffer.Properties.GetOrCreateSingletonProperty("com.entrian.ValueTagger", delegate () {
            IClassifier classifier = AggregatorService.GetClassifier(buffer);
            return new ValueTagger(classifier, textView, buffer) as ITagger<T>;
        }) as ITagger<T>;
```

The vsixmanifest looks like this:

```
<Content>
  <VsPackage>|%CurrentProject%;PkgdefProjectOutputGroup|</VsPackage>
  <MefComponent>|%CurrentProject%|</MefComponent>
</Content>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your package offers a logging service. Visual Studio has a full infrastructure for this: [How to: Provide a Service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb164693.aspx)

What you need, in the package code, is therefore to:

1. create some interface that represents the service contract (like `IMyLogger` for example)
2. register this service (this will eventually go in the registry at setup time so VS knows in a static way your package implements this)

   ```
   [ProvideService(typeof(SMyLogger))]
   public sealed class EntrianInlineWatchPackage : Package
   {. . .}
   ```
3. implement the service (follow the link above for more).

In all other packages or addins or extensions that will use this service (so in your Tagger code), you should be able to [get a reference to this service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165052.aspx), for example:

```
IMyLogger logger = ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SMyLogger)) as IMyLogger;
```

and, magically, Visual Studio should load the package, if needed (thanks to the registry settings declared through the `ProvideService` attribute).

PS: Note this will require that you define `IMyLogger` in an assembly accessible by both the Package and the Tagger assemblies. Or you could use a well known interface that suits your need.

Comment: This looks perfect, except for one thing: how do I call `GetService` before the Package has loaded?  In my current code, when something other than my Package (eg. the Tagger) needs a service, it calls the Package's `GetService` method, but the point of all this is that the Tagger is loading before the Package, so I can't do that...?

Comment: You should not call your package's code from the Tagger code (so don't call your package's GetService method from there). Check out the 2nd link ("How to: Get a Service") : the tagger code doesn't know who implements the SMyLogger service, it asks it though standard VS methods (it just happens you did implemented both sides, but that's irrelevant, it's some kind of dependency injection + runtime discovery mechanism if you will).

Comment: I understand what not to do.  :-)  What I don't understand is: what is `ServiceProvider` in your example?  When I try to call `ServiceProvider.GetService()`, I get "An object reference is required", which seems reasonable - on which object am I supposed to call `GetService`? (I'm finding `ServiceProvider` in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell` - is that the wrong one?)

Comment: Have you seen the GetGlobalService static method on package (In the 2nd link, it's in the 'Getting a service from a tool window or control container' chapter)?

Comment: Yes, but it makes me nervous that it can fail if called before any packages are loaded - what if my Tagger is loaded before any Package?  (Or is that not possible because Taggers are loaded by the editor, which is itself a package...?)

Comment: That's the whole point of this Service infrastructure in VS. You declare your service in a static way (in the registry) and VS will ensure the package that provides this service will be loaded when someone (Tagger here) asks for it.

Comment: I mean that calling `GetGlobalService()` can fail if you call it before any Package is loaded.

Comment: I don't think so. What do you mean by "any package"? All VS packages are loaded. VS is itself just a shell + a sum of packages. Even the menu system is a package, the solution manager is a package, etc.

Comment: From the docs: "The static GetGlobalService method relies on a cached service provider that is initialized the first time any VSPackage derived from Package is sited."  So if my Tagger loads before the first Package is loaded, this will fail.  But as you say, since VS itself is made up of Packages, this probably isn't a problem.